# How to run two projects under single domain?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

Hi i want to run two projects under single domain.

Right now only one project is running (means url of first project is running), If i passsed the url of 2nd project then it shows me that url doesn't exist.

I am doing this first time and i don't know what to do ?

So please anybody can tell me how i can done that, and which are the file si have to edit and how.

Comment: You probably need to create virtual hosts or use the [directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) to specify your individual server endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualHosts to create a subdomain.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

and edit your question with the mod_wsgi configuration you are using so can see how you are trying to do it now.